Java OpenCv to Maven
Is there any way to get OpenCV from repository? Which artifact should I add to pom.xml? Every tutorial I'd found is from '14 and it seems like something changed - they say it is'nt in official Maven repository yet, but I've found entry:
when I'm using System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME). Can I add this library in a way that would make my project include it and 'forget' about manually adding it to classpath?

I recommend to search for artifacts in Central via: https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.opencv/opencv and that shows a pom snippet which you can directly copy into your own pom file... And to use it you don't need to load it as a JNI library because it's a jar file which can you add to your classpath...

This is the one I usually use: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openpnp/opencv
Example from the page:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
    <version>4.9.0-0</version>
</dependency>

Note that it uses a slightly different API from the official bindings:
https://github.com/openpnp/opencv?tab=readme-ov-file#api
